# Reactivating a Phone Without Service

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-droid-incredible-2

I recently got an old HTC Droid Incredible 2 with Verizon, that doesn't have service anymore. I wanted to give the phone a "clean slate" so I did a factory reset. However, when I booted it up again, it said that it needed to make a phone call (through Verizon) in order to re-activate, and will not let me proceed without doing this. I have pretty much no idea what I should do now. I could try rooting it and installing CyanogenMod or something, and hope that it would work, but I'm not sure if an unactivated phone can do that. What should I do?

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled on the phone after a factory reset? If it is, you should be able to root it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the SIM card under the battery to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this. I don't know if this is the best way to do this, and if this is unique to just this phone, but here's what worked for me:

1. Rebooted the phone
2. Unlocked it at the lock screen that popped up
3. When I came to the activation setup pages, I pulled down the notifications shade
4. "Quick Settings" >> "All Settings" >> Home Button

I'm not sure how exactly this worked (glitch or bug, maybe?), but it did. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. Now [root](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/14785-inc2guide-gain-s-off-and-root-the-htc-incredible-2-works-on-234/) that phone :)

Answer (score 0):

That phone would most likely be tied to Verizon, if it's from a contract. You would first need to root and unlock the phone - so that it can be used with other networks - before you can flash CM on it.

Comment: Verizon is a CDMA carrier, so there's not really a concept of "unlocking" most of their phones. Some also have GSM radios, but many do not (don't know about the OP's specifically).

Comment: @eldarerathis The dinc2 is indeed an un-lockable, GSM-capable phone, but unlocking it probably isn't the issue here, and definitely not required to flash CM.